# How to arrange ny dataframe by number of characters in column?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataset:

```
id     value
1    "include details"
2    "language"
2    "describe what you've tried"
```

How could I arrange it by number of characters in column value with strings? `%>% arrange(value)` doesnt work. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `stringr` package:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
                 value = c("include details","language","describe what you've tried"))
```

Code:

```
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  arrange(str_count(value))
```

Output:

```
  id                      value
1  2                   language
2  1            include details
3  3 describe what you've tried
```

Answer (score 1):

`arrange` it by `nchar` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% arrange(nchar(value))

#  id                      value
#1  2                   language
#2  1            include details
#3  2 describe what you've tried
```

Or in descending order -

```
df %>% arrange(desc(nchar(value)))

#  id                     value
#1  2 describe what you've tried
#2  1           include details
#3  2                  language
```

---

Or in base R -

```
df[order(nchar(df$value)), ]
```